# levelplot - how to use it, any simple examples?

Tags: r, 3d

I woud like to understand how levelplot works. I have almost no experience with plots and R.

What confuses me, is how should I interpret for example x~y*z ?
Lets assume I have a function, and  I would like to show how often certain value occurs by using 3d plot. I would have hence x = x, y = f(x) and z = count. How to obtain such simple plot by using levelplot (or something else if it is not appriopriate).

In addition, should I group "count" myself - 3 columns in my data from, or just have 2 columns - x and f(x) and have duplications?

Hope my question is clear, I tried to read [levelplot documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/levelplot.html), however I could not find any tutorial that teaches basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example is from the `?levelplot` documentation.

The formula `z~x*y` means that `z` is a function of `x`, `y` and the **interaction** between `x` and `y`.  Had the function been `z~x+y` it would have meant that `z` is a function of `x` and `y`, ignoring any interaction.

You can read more about the formula interface in the help for `?formula`.

```
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
          colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE)
```

[image]